# find open source consumer dataset

Tags: dataset, open-source, kaggle

A while ago somebody gave me a tip about which forum to post questions about finding open source data sources on stackexchange, but I don't remember which forum.  If someone could let me know that would be great.

I'm trying to find an open source data set that has consumer purchase related data, with fields like:

purchase timestamp, delivery timestamp, customerId, store chain, store department, product category, product company, product brand, product size, purchase quantity, purchase amount, offerId, product price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know what forum you heard about, but I may be able to help. :) I couldn't find exactly what you were looking for, but maybe one of these might work?

- [This dataset has information on online auctions](https://www.kaggle.com/onlineauctions/online-auctions-dataset), including:

  - **auctionid**: unique identifier of an auction
  - **bid**: the proxy bid placed by a bidder
  - **bidtime**: the time in days that the bid was placed, from the start 
    of the auction
  - **bidderrate**: eBay feedback rating of the bidder
  - **openbid**: the opening bid set by the seller
  - **price**: the closing price that the item sold for (equivalent to the 
    second highest bid + an increment)
- [This dataset has store-wide sales data from 45 different department stores](https://www.kaggle.com/manjeetsingh/retaildataset) including information on the different sales they all ran.
- [This dataset has 12 million sales records of liquor in Iowa](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/iowa-liquor-sales), but not a lot of customer information.

Comment: Thank you, the iowa liquor sales dataset was very helpful